# Use of HFC-134a as a propellant

Tags: post-grant, invalidation, us7174856

In reference to the patent: [US 7,174,856 B2](https://www.google.com/patents/US7174856)

Will this patent become invalidated or need revision based on the [SNAP law](http://www.epa.gov/ozone/snap/regulations.html) in effect mid-2016?

Answer (score 2):

This change in EPA rules covers production and use of *products* containing HFC-134a, but it does not affect the validity of the patent (a patent is not a product).

Further, the independent claim in the patent grant covers any inert gas in a class of compounds:

> 1. A method for modifying animal behavior when animal performs an undesirable behavior, comprising discharging an inert gas stream at an animal body from an inert gas spray canister wherein the gas is inert gas of Tumorigen compound class.

where the compound class is defined in the specification as:

> Other condensed inert gas cleaning spray can contain different
>   high-pressure inert gases such as Chlorodifluoromethane (also known as
>   Algeon, Freon etc. ) as well as other gases of the Tumorigen compound
>   class. Some of the Tumorigen compound class gases containing
>   fluorocarbon are now outlawed in some western countries due to their
>   harmful effect on the ozone layer. One other inert gas compound which
>   is environmentally friendly, used in computer and other hardware
>   cleaning spray containers such as from DuPont is the Ethane,
>   1,1,1,2-tetrafloro also known as Arcton 134a and the like.

So the EPA rule change only affects production of a product containing HFC-134a (Arcton 134a), but the scope of the patent leaves other compounds that may be used as alternatives.